# dont alert using prometheus/alertmanager at particular time (maintance window) if machine goes down

Tags: amazon-ec2, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, pagerduty

I have ec2 machine on which i have setup alerting (if it goes down) using tags promethues/alertmanager. The maintance is scheduled fot that
machine at 6 am in the morning twice a week

I dont want to get alerts for those machines in that time. How can this be achieved ?

PD is used for alerting (i dont want to be done at service level).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there are three ways to avoid alerting at maintenance time:

1. **Using service discovery**: depending on the service discovery you are using, you can remove the services from Prometheus during the maintenance time. Then, they won't trigger any alert at Prometheus level.
2. **Using silence in AlertManager**: alert manager let you schedule [silences](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/#silences) that will automatically snooze alerts. Depending on your version or alert manager you may use the v1 API not very well documented or the v2 API that uses [open API](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/api/v2/openapi.yaml). This requires an external scheduler and a bit of tinkering (curl is usually enough).
3. **Using inhibition**: the principle is to define a rule that triggers a silent alert during maintenance time and use it for snoozing other alerts. See my answer in [this question](/questions/59157537/how-to-snooze-prometheus-alert-for-specific-time/59164932). This solution doesn't require external components but complexifies your configuration.

Which solution is the best depends on your use case and environment. Giving a few cases:

- If you use a dynamic service discovery (say consul), it should be part of the normal workflow and comes at no cost.
- If you are on a traditional setup with known servers and operations done by hand, then scripts to snooze alerts can be integrated in your playbook. It becomes part of the normal workflow of update.
- If you are in an environment where there is a strong separation between the team handling alerts and the ones doing upgrades, then using a Prometheus only solution, with well scheduled maintenance time, would probably better. The monitoring team being supposed to be expert on the tool and can handle the added complexity.